# Prove that the limit is 0

Tags: limits

Find $$\lim_{x\to0}x^{2/3}(\ln x)^2$$ where $x>0$.

I used Desmos (a graphing software) to find that the limit is $0$. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: You can use l'Hospital rull.

Comment: If you are already familiar with the fact that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} x\ln x=0$, you can reduce your problem to it algebraically.

Comment: Or, if you want to avoid the fuss of the fractions, set $x=y^3$ and the limit is of the form $9y^2lny$ where $y$ approaches zero from the positive side. Then use Sassatelli's suggestion (a well established limit)

Answer (score 3):

L'Hospital's Rule two times.

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln^2{x}}{x^{-2/3}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} -\frac{3*2\ln{x}}{2x^{-2/3}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{9*2}{4x^{-2/3}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{9x^{2/3}}{2}=0
$$

Since

$$
\left( \ln^2{x} \right)'=2\frac{\ln{x}}{x}\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \left(x^{-2/3}\right)'= -\frac{2x^{-5/3}}{3}
$$

And in second iteration.
$$
\left( \ln{x} \right)'=\frac{1}{x}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,  \left(x^{-2/3}\right)'= -\frac{2x^{-5/3}}{3}
$$